# JsTree - Trigger action after deleting a node

Tags: javascript, dom, events, jstree

Really simple query here, jsTree docs are horrible, and a lot of other solutions I tried didn't work out so asking.

I am using a custom menu to delete node, and then I want to update some mark up associated with that node from my DOM. Node deletes correctly, however none of the other DOM actions work! Actually the element itself is not found. Tried logging the length, and triple checked selectors, no luck.

```
$("#tree").on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
        var currentNode = $(this).jstree('get_selected')[0];
        // Do something with the node, works perfectly

        }).on('delete_node.jstree', function() {
            // NOT WORKING
            $('.node-props-list').hide();
        }).jstree({
            core: {
                data: formatted,
                check_callback: true,
                loaded: true
            },
            plugins: ['contextmenu'],
            contextmenu: {
                items: function ($node) {
                    var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true);
                    return {
                        "Remove": {
                            "separator_before": false,
                            "separator_after": false,
                            "label": "Remove",
                            "action": function () {
                                // NOT WORKING EITHER
                                $('.node-props-list').hide();
                                tree.delete_node($node);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out on my own. The action has to be done after the delete statement. Changing the order of those lines fixed it. Their documentation is abysmal. Just posting the `remove` part:

```
"Remove": {
    "separator_before": false,
    "separator_after": false,
    "label": "Remove",
    "action": function () {
        // NOT WORKING EITHER
        $('.node-props-list').hide();
        tree.delete_node($node);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone stuck!